# Debugging js inside html page in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, webstorm

I have WebStrom 7. I create a following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function go() {
            alert("hello"); // here a set a breakpoint
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="go()">
<p>
    Test
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: WebStorm]

If I debug this page, I do not get to breakpoint. The page simply displayed in the browser.
[image: index.html in chrome]

If I create a js file and move js code there and add to html link on js file, when the breakpoint is triggered.

How i can debug js inside html page?

[image: Chrome with WebStorm]

Comment: Did you actually launch the debugging process? JS breakpoints from WebStorm only run, when you explicitly use the debug-functionality. Check `Run > Debug` for a first try. For more information check [this guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/quickstart/#RunandDebugYourApplication).

Comment: I've tried it. did not help.

Comment: I can't see the 'Jetbrains IDE Support is debugging this tab' bar in your browser. Seems the extension is not connected. Please can you provide a screenshot of your Debug tool window - what is written there? Is debugger connected?

Comment: Works just fine here (although it's PhpStorm v7.0 on Windows 7): 1) http://imgur.com/4ECIUCt,aqmHzUR  2) http://imgur.com/4ECIUCt,aqmHzUR#1 . Could you save whole project (including .idea subfolder) and share it somewhere?

Comment: I use 64 bit Windows.

Comment: File->New Project->Type: Empty Project. Then i add index.html, edit configuration and start debug

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7236112/newTest.zip

Comment: works fine for me using your project. Please check if you are using the latest version of JetBrains IDE Support (1.27). Please also proviode the content of extension console (chrome://extensions/?id=hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji, click 'generated background page.html' link to open it, make sure the Console tab is selected and filter is set to 'All'

Comment: I can't debug js code inside in html...

Comment: I install WebStorm 7.0.1 on another laptop and i have the same problem

Comment: I create a new project and i don't now how, but it worked. Thnks